# Optimize Firefox / Chromium for low memory and cpu systems

Tags: firefox, chromium

What settings can be modified/added, to optimize Firefox / Chromium for low memory/cpu systems such as raspberry pi4, or similar configuration devices, besides them autoconfiguring for low memory and cpu?

Answer (score -1):

for `Firefox`, following tweaks seem to have a more responsive effect and longer to occupy memory.

```
# firefox memory optimize, to be set in about:config or user.js in firefor profile dir
browser.tabs.animate –>disable
browser.cache.memory.capacity –>0
javascript.options.jit.chrome –>true
javascript.options.jit.content –>true
network.http.pipelining –>true
network.http.proxy pipelining –>true
plugin.expose_full_path –>true
browser.tabs.remote.autostart
dom.ipc.processCount ->2
toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled ->false
browser.sessionhistory.max_total_viewers ->4
browser.sessionhistory.max_entries ->10
browser.sessionstore.interval ->60000
dom.max_script_run_time
browser.cache.disk.capacity ->50000
browser.cache.offline.capacity ->512000
```

apart, settings from https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js, disabling many features and hardening security seems to save cpu and memory occupancy.

for `Chromium`, following tweaks have a similar effect:

```
# following need to be passed as commandline args to chromium
## process count
--process-per-site
# or
--single-process # bad in terms of security

## hardware accel
--ignore-gpu-blocklist # use with care, gpu may not be support and cause instability
--enable-gpu-rasterization
--enable-zero-copy

## video decode
--disable-features=UseSkiaRenderer
--enable-features=+VaapiVideoDecoder
--enable-features=+CanvasOopRasterization

## use opengl
--use-gl=egl
## or vulkan if supported (will disable gl)
--enable-features=+Vulkan
```

Additionally, setting user / cache data dirs to tmpfs (RAM) and using `profile-sync-daemon`, to restore persistance across sessions, though this approach is more applicable for saving cpu and sdcard write based failures than for saving memory.

```
--user-data-dir=/tmp/.chromium-user-data
--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/.chromium-cache
```

Please feel free to suggest alternatives or additions.